# Line with symbol after integral

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, integral

[image]

I'm trying to do line and `$t_b$` exactly as on the image, but couldn't find out how.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you don't provide any code, nobody can't guess what you did wrong. Also, I don't see any problem in this picture. Vertical alignment seems to be fine, so you should also explain what you want to obtain.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you tried `\Big\vert_{t_b}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here the example of the image below.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\delta x_b \times \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial \dot{x}}\Bigr|_{t_b} -0\]
\end{document}
```

[image]